# Grabbing a timesheet HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I need to grab a timesheets from a website. I want to store/add this timesheet to a data table in my C# Application.

The structure of the data table looks like this:

```
1. |  Day  |  Time  | Status |
2. ..1.......7:00.........IN
3. ..1.......9:45.......OUT
4. ..1......10:15........IN
5. ..1......15:45......OUT
6. ..1.......8:45.....TOTAL
7. ..2      ..        ..
```

My C# code for the DataTable:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable("Worksheet");
table.Columns.Add("Day");
table.Columns.Add("Time");
table.Columns.Add("Status");
```

I tried different variants and I always mess up with all the data.

For testing purpose I made a new Winform with a "textbox" (for the sitepath) and "button"(to start the process)

Then I want HTMLAgilityPack to get all the data. one example:

```
public string[] GREYsource;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    var fileName = txtPath.Text;                    // I downloaded the HTML-File
    doc.Load(fileName);

    string strGREYInner;

    foreach (HtmlNode td in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class=\"tblDataGreyNH\"]"))
    {
        strGREYInner = td.InnerText.Trim();
        string shorted = strGREYInner.Replace("\t", ""); string shorted2 = shorted.Replace("\n\n\n\n", "\n\n\n"); string shorted3 = shorted2.Replace("\n\n\n", "\n\n"); string shorted4 = shorted3.Replace("\n\n", "\n");
        GREYsource = shorted4.Split(new Char[] { '\n', });
    }

    foreach (string str in GREYsource)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

1. Problem: the result contains a lot of tabs(/t) and newlines(/n) I need to trim.
2. Problem: This isn't a good way to do it, IMO. And this would just grab the Totaltimes.

It can be done better.

This is just a example I tried (other codes just went a pile of junk)

I attached the HTML-structure below:

Overview(picture):
[image: http://www.abload.de/img/overviewzoj18.png]

A bit more in depth:

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <style type="text/css">
  </style>
  <body id="body" onload="handleMenuOverlapLogo();onload_column_expand();;firstElementFocus();">

    <.. some (java)scripts>             /* has to be ignoered. not necessary */
    <.. some other divs>              /* has to be ignoered. not necessary */
    <div id="rowContent">             /* This <div> contains the content i need */
      <div id="titleTab">             /* Title is not necessary */
      </div>                    
      <div id="rowContentInner">          /* Here the content starts */
        <table class="tblList">
          <tbody>
            <tr>              /* not necessary */
            <tr class="tblHeader">      /* not necessary */
            <tr class="tblHeader">      /* not necessary */
            <tr class="tblDataWhiteNH">   /*  IN : */
              <td class="tblHeader" style="font-weight: bold; text-align: right"> In </td>
              <td nowrap="">        /* "tblDataWhiteNH" always contains 7 "td nowrap"
              <td nowrap="">
              <td nowrap="">        /* Example: if it contains a value */
                <table width="100%" border="0" align="center">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="25%" align="left"> </td>
                      <td nowrap="" width="50%" align="center"> 7:53 </td>  /* value = 7:53 (THIS!) */
                      <td width="25%" align="right"> </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td nowrap="">
              <td nowrap="">        /* Example: if it contains no value */
                <table width="100%" border="0" align="center">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="25%" align="left"> </td>
                      <td nowrap="" width="50%" align="center">       /* no value = 0:00 (THIS!) */
                      <td width="25%" align="right"> </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td nowrap="">
              <td nowrap="">
            <tr class="tblDataWhiteNH">   /* OUT : */
              <td class="tblHeader" style="font-weight: bold; text-align: right"> Out </td>
              <td nowrap="">        /* "tblDataWhiteNH" always contains 7 "td nowrap".
              <td nowrap="">
              <td nowrap="">        /* Example: if it contains a value */
                <table width="100%" border="0" align="center">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="25%" align="left"> </td>
                      <td nowrap="" width="50%" align="center"> 7:53 </td>  /* value = 7:53 (THIS!) */
                      <td width="25%" align="right"> </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td nowrap="">
              <td nowrap="">        /* Example: if it contains no value */
                <table width="100%" border="0" align="center">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="25%" align="left"> </td>
                      <td nowrap="" width="50%" align="center">       /* no value = 0:00 (THIS!) */
                      <td width="25%" align="right"> </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td nowrap="">
              <td nowrap="">
            <tr class="tblDataGreyNH">    /*  IN : */
            <tr class="tblDataGreyNH">    /* OUT : */
            ...               /* "tblDataGreyNH" is built up the same way like "tblDataWhiteNH".
            ...               /* sometimes there could be more "tblDataWhiteNH" and "tblDataGreyNH". */
            ...               /* Usally there are just the "tblDataWhiteNH"(IN/OUT) */
            <tr class="tblHeader">      /* not necessary */
                            /* It continues f.egs. with "tblDataWhite" if the last above header was a "tblDatagrey" */
                            /* and versa vice ("grey" if there was a "white" before.) */
            <tr class="tblDataWhiteNH">   /* Worked : */
              <td class="tblHeader" style="font-weight: bold; text-align: right"> Total Time </td>
              <td> 07:47 </td>      /* value = 7:47 (THIS!) */
              <td> 04:48 </td>      
              <td> 00:00 </td>      /* no value = 0:00 (THIS!) */
              <td> 00:00 </td>      
              <td> 07:42 </td>      
              <td> 00:00 </td>      
              <td> 00:00 </td>      
            </tr>
            <tr class="tblDataGreyNH">    /* Total : */
              <td class="tblHeader" style="font-weight: bold; text-align: right"> Regular Time </td>
              <td> 07:47 </td>      /* value = 7:47 (THIS!) */
              <td> 04:48 </td>      
              <td> </td>          /* no value = 0:00 (THIS!) */
              <td> </td>          
              <td> 07:42 </td>      
              <td> </td>
              <td> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tblHeader">      /* not necessary */
            <tr valign="top">       /* not necessary */
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

a copy of the original HTML: http://time.wnb.dk/123/

I Hope anyone could help me get this to work.

---

Okay let me explain it with a picture. https://www.abload.de/img/eeeqnuwu.png
On the Picture you see the website + a table below, how the result should look like.

Declaring the Datatable isnt the problem.
The main problem is I can't get htmlagility to spit out right results and if it did, its almost buggy.
Some of the selectnodes I tried got the output messed up after a while. As yet I wasn't able to get "all" data from the table on the website, just some values, but often buggy.
So I'm actually searching for someone who could take a look on this and maybe help me to find the right selectnodes.

Comment: The question as it stands is very unclear - what are you actually asking? Where exactly are you stuck? What exactly are you looking for help with?

Comment: Sorry for my unclear explaining, im not that perfect in english and not a pro in c#. i just want a datatable in c# from the html-code i posted. And the (datatable)rows should look like this in c#: `table.Rows.Add("Daynumber, Timevalue, Status");`. My problem is that i always mess up with all the "td's" and i don't get a usefull result/datatable. It seems I stuck at the html-nodes.

Comment: Still seems to be unclear. I posted a picture, which hopefully will explain it a bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand what you want to do but here is a sample code that should help you get started. I strongly suggest you have a look at [XPATH](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) to understand it.

```
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(yourFile);

        // get all TR with a specific class name, starting from root (/), and recursively (//)
        foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='tblDataGreyNH' or @class='tblDataWhiteNH']"))
        {
            // get all TD below the current node with a specific class name
            HtmlNode inOrOut = node.SelectSingleNode("td[@class='tblHeader']");
            if (inOrOut != null)
            {
                string io = inOrOut.InnerText.Trim();
                Console.WriteLine(io.ToUpper());
                if (io.Contains("Time"))
                {
                    // normalize-space gets rid or whitespaces (\r,\n, etc.)
                    // text() gets the node's inner text
                    foreach (HtmlNode td in node.SelectNodes("td[normalize-space(@class)='' and normalize-space(text())!='' and normalize-space(text())!='00:00']"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("value:" + td.InnerText.Trim());
                    }
                }
            }

            // gets all TD below the current node that define the NOWRAP attribute
            HtmlNodeCollection tdNoWraps = node.SelectNodes("td[@nowrap]"); 
            if (tdNoWraps != null)
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode tdNoWrap in tdNoWraps)
                {
                    string value = tdNoWrap.InnerText.Trim();
                    if (value == string.Empty)
                        continue;

                    Console.WriteLine("value:" + value);
                }
            }
        }
```

It will output this from your sample page:

```
IN
value:7:47
value:7:46
value:7:45
value:7:51
OUT
value:15:35
value:15:33
value:12:38
value:8:59
IN
value:12:38
value:8:59
OUT
value:15:35
TOTAL TIME
value:07:48
value:07:47
value:07:50
value:01:08
REGULAR TIME
value:07:48
value:07:47
value:07:50
value:01:08
```

Comment: wow, that's exactly what i am looking for.. Thank you so much!! Btw I didn't know that you can use 'or/and' in Xpath(now I know what the syntax is called) to parse it. Your answer helped me a lot.